# ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument | error in pickle

Tags: python, async-await, pickle, python-aiofiles

Am using this code to read a file with pickle but inside an async function

```
    async with aiofiles.open("owners.pkl", mode="rb") as file:
    owner_dict = pickle.loads(await file.read())
```

But I get this error

```
    owner_dict = pickle.loads(await file.read())
    _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xef'.
```

I just want a valid way to open files and read or write in them using pickle inside async-await functions

Comment: Does unpickle work without async-await?

Comment: @MichaelButscher am not sure but I don't think so, I just want a valid way to open files and write in them with pickle inside an async function. doing that with the regular way gives me an error.

Comment: Maybe you should start with the regular way and find the error there before increasing complexity with async functions.